# Spring boot Oauth2 - Security incompatibility between Authorization and Resource server

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to build an Oauth2 authorization server using spring. The thing is I am not able to make it work together the login and authorization form and a resource server to retrieve user data using an oauth2 token.

This is my main config apart from user services and repositories...

WebSecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("classpath:schema.sql")
    private Resource schemaScript;

    @Value("classpath:data.sql")
    private Resource dataScript;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
        final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        return initializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter checkTokenEndpointFilter() {
        ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter filter = new ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter("/oauth/check_token");
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        filter.setAllowOnlyPost(true);
        return filter;
    }


    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(schemaScript);
        populator.addScript(dataScript);
        return populator;
    }

    private DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(3)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

**UserController**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read_user_profile')")
    @GetMapping("/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<User> getUser(@RequestParam String email) {
        return userService.findAll().stream().filter(x -> x.getEmail().equals(email)).findAny();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/user", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void postMessage(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.save(user);
    }

}
```

As you can see I assigned them an order. The thing is, if WebSecurityConfig is the first one, I am able to go to /login and /oauth/authorize screen but the user controller has not any security layer and it is open (no token needed) :S

If the order is the reverse, I can't see the login page but I see a 404. It redirects from /oauth/authorize by the way. But I am able to access the user controller using the generated token.

What I am doing wrong? Is it not possible to have both in the same module?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not 'order' problem.

`@PreAuthorize` annotation is used by Method security.
If you want to let it work, you need to `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` annotation.

But if you just want to protect your resource by OAuth, why don't you configure using url base security constraint at ResourceServerConfig?

For example, my ResourceServerConfig works fine like:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }
```

Comment: Because that does not work. It seems like the security config of the resource server is not taking into account.

Comment: Did you try my advice? I showed you 2 solutions. My code has no problem and works perfect. If your code didnt work there is something missing or wrong part.

Comment: Yeah it works using your adivce but not using annotations. Appart from this, my main issue is to have both configurations working together. If I change the order of one of them I can get the resource using the token but not log in in the form following the implicit flow. And the reverse. Do you have any suggestion to that? @Jes

Comment: I menthoned @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true) annotation. It doesnt work?

Comment: It works but by defining MethodSecurityConfig. But that is relating to use annotations in the method to set Oauth2 scopes not relating to my question which is if you have defined a global security config the resource security config is ignored. If you change the order the other one is ignored. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1024